# XMLHttpRequest endpoint blocked while signing S3 request because no HTTPS, eventhough everything is on HTTPS

Tags: javascript, python, ssl, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to sign a huge video upload, because I want to upload it directly to S3. It works on localhost, but on my live site it fails to sign the request because of:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/profile' was loaded
over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 
'http://www.example.com/sign_s3/?file_name=17mbvid.mp4&file_type=video/mp4'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I am hosting everything on heroku, every page is already using HTTPS and its not possible to open it in HTTP, because I redirect all traffic to HTTPS. I am using the letsencrypt SSL certificate.

So far I have no idea where to look, the only information I found, is that I need a valid SSL certificate, which I have.

Here is the JS function:

```
function getSignedRequest(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "/sign_s3?file_name=" + file.name + "&file_type=" + file.type);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log('got signed request');              
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(response);
                console.log('uploadFile', response.url)
                uploadFile(file, response.data, response.url);
            } else {
                console.log("Could not get signed URL.");
            }
        }
    };
    //console.log('send');  
    xhr.send();
}
```

Right after the error in the console I see this console log:

```
Could not get signed URL.
```

which means it fails here:

```
if (xhr.status === 200)
```

On the server:

```
@app.route('/sign_s3/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
@check_confirmed
def sign_s3():
    if "localhost" in request.url_root:
        file_name = str(current_user.id) + "local-profil-video." + request.args.get('file_name').split(".")[-1]
    else:
        file_name = str(current_user.id) + "-profil-video." + request.args.get('file_name').split(".")[-1]

    file_type = request.args.get('file_type')

    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=app.config['MY_AWS_ID'],
        aws_secret_access_key=app.config['MY_AWS_SECRET'],
        region_name='eu-central-1'
    )

    s3 = session.client('s3')

    presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket = 'adultpatreon',
    Key = 'videos/' + file_name,
    Fields = {"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
    Conditions = [
      {"acl": "public-read"},
      {"Content-Type": file_type}
    ],
    ExpiresIn = 3600
    )

    if current_user.profile_video != None:
        delete_file_from_aws("videos/", current_user.profile_video)
    setattr(current_user, "profile_video", file_name)
    db_session.commit()

    return json.dumps({'data': presigned_post, 'url': 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/' + 'videos/' + file_name})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of researching I decided to rebuild this function and use AJAX get, which I am more familiar with. I also changed the way I pass/recieve the query string arguments to the best way, which is actually used in flask/python.

```
function getSignedRequest(file) {
$.ajax({
    url : "/sign_s3/" + file.name + "/" + file.type,
    type : "get",
    success : function(response) {
        console.log("success file up, follow", response);   
        var json_response = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(json_response);
        uploadFile(file, json_response.data, json_response.url);
    },
    error : function(xhr) {
        console.log("file up failed", xhr);
    }
});
```

}

And on server side I changed how `file.name` and `file.type` are recieved:

```
# Sign request for direct file upload through client for video
@app.route('/sign_s3/<path:file_name_data>/<path:file_type_data>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
@check_confirmed
def sign_s3(file_name_data, file_type_data):
    #etc...
```

Now it works perfectly. I think they way I was recieving the query string arguments on the server was not correct, probably it would also work with the old `getSignedRequest` function (untested).